# Python 3 - How to properly setup this multiprocessing job?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a file with like 10,000 rows, each row represents parameters to a download job. I have like 5 custom downloaders. Each job can take anywhere from 5 seconds to 2 minutes. How would I create something that iterates through the 10,000 rows, assigning each job to a downloader if that downloader isn't currently working?

EDIT:

The difficult part for me is that each `Downloader` is an instance of a class, and the differences between the instances are the port_numbers I specify when I instantiate each of the 5 `Downloader` objects. So I have `a = Downloader(port_number=7751) ... e = Downloader(port_number=7755)`. Then, if I were to use a `Downloader` I would do `a.run(row)`.

How do I define the workers as these `a, b, c, d, e` rather than a `downloader function`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it - the simplest way would be to just use `multiprocessing.Pool` and let it organize the workers for you - 10k rows is not all that much, let's say that an average URL is even a full kilobyte long it will still take only 10MB of memory and memory is cheap.

So, just read the file in memory and map it to `multiprocessing.Pool` to do your bidding:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def downloader(param):  # our downloader process
    # download code here
    # param will hold a line from your file (including newline at the end, strip before use)
    # e.g. res = requests.get(param.strip())
    return True  # lets provide some response back

if __name__ == "__main__":  # important protection for cross-platform use

    with open("your_file.dat", "r") as f:  # open your file
        download_jobs = f.readlines()  # store each line in a list

    download_pool = Pool(processes=5)  # make our pool use 5 processes
    responses = download_pool.map(downloader, download_jobs)  # map our data, line by line
    download_pool.close()  # lets exit cleanly
    # you can check the responses for each line in the `responses` list
```

You can also use `threading` instead of `multiprocessing` (or `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` as a drop-in replacement for this) to do everything within a single process if you need shared memory. A single thread is more than enough for download purposes unless you're doing additional processing.

#### UPDATE

If you want your downloaders to run as class instances, you can transform the `downloader` function into a factory for your `Downloader` instances, and then just pass what you need to instantiate those instances alongside your URLs. Here is a simple Round-Robin approach:

```
from itertools import cycle
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Downloader(object):

    def __init__(self, port_number=8080):
        self.port_number = port_number

    def run(self, url):
        print("Downloading {} on port {}".format(url, self.port_number))

def init_downloader(params):  # our downloader initializator
    downloader = Downloader(**params[0])  # instantiate our downloader
    downloader.run(params[1])  # run our downloader
    return True  # you can provide your

if __name__ == "__main__":  # important protection for cross-platform use

    downloader_params = [  # Downloaders will be initialized using these params
        {"port_number": 7751},
        {"port_number": 7851},
        {"port_number": 7951}
    ]

    downloader_cycle = cycle(downloader_params)  # use cycle for round-robin distribution
    with open("your_file.dat", "r") as f:  # open your file
        # read our file line by line and attach downloader params to it
        download_jobs = [[next(downloader_cycle), row.strip()] for row in f]

    download_pool = Pool(processes=5)  # make our pool use 5 processes
    responses = download_pool.map(init_downloader, download_jobs)  # map our data
    download_pool.close()  # lets exit cleanly
    # you can check the responses for each line in the `responses` list
```

Keep in mind that this is not the most balanced solution as it can happen to have two `Downloader` instances with the same port running, but it will average over large enough data.

If you want to make sure that you don't have two `Downloader` instances running off of the same port, you'll either need to build your own pool, or you'll need to create a central process that will issue ports to your `Downloader` instances when they need them.

Comment: So each `Downloader` is an instance of a class, and the differences between the instances is the `port_number` I specify when I instantiate each of the 5 `Downloader` objects. So I have `a =  Downloader(port_number=7751) ... e = Downloader(port_number=7755)`. Then, if I were to use a `Downloader` I would do `a.run(row)`. Can you suggest a way to define my workers as these `a, b, c, d, e` rather than the `downloader` function in your example?

Comment: @user1367204 - you should've specified that in your original question. Multiprocessing and pre-initialized classes are not friends (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186168/7553525)) - the issue is that your 'Downloader' classes will be instantiated in your main process, and when you're spawning a new process it won't have the access to it.

Comment: @user1367204 - is instantiation of those 'Downloader' classes an expensive operation? i.e. can we re-instantiate a new one whenever we start a download (still respecting the port number, of course)?

Comment: Reinstantiation is no problem in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Read in your 10000 rows into a list of strings.

```
with open('foo.dat') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

Assuming that the data does not include a port number and the edited question mentions 5 ports, you should add that to the data.

```
data = [(p, d) for p, d in zip(itertools.cycle([7751, 7752, 7753, 7754, 7755]), data)]
```

Write a function that takes one of those tuples as an argument, splits it, creates a Downloader object and runs it.

```
def worker(target):
    port, params = target
    d = Downloader(port_number=port)
    d.run(params)
    return params # for lack of more information.
```

Use the [`imap_unordered`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered) method of a `multiprocessing.Pool`, giving it the function you've defined and the list of tuples as arguments.

The iterator returned by `imap_unordered` will start yielding results as soon as they become available. You could print them to show the progress.

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
for params in p.imap_unordered(worker, data):
    print('Finished downloading', params)
```

**Edit**

P.S: if the only method of your `Downloader` object you'll ever use is `run()`, *it should not be an object*. It is a function in disguise! Look up the "stop writing classes" video on Youtube and watch it.