# How to use parallel processing (multiprocessing) to run GPU function 100 times?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, gpu, python-multiprocessing

I have a function on Google Colab in python that I want to run 100 times. This function uses the GPU (specifically Pytorch) on Google Colab.

What is the fastest way I can run this function 100 times? The order does not matter.

My motivation is that I am trying to run a bootstrapping experiment. So I am trying to run the same function with different random noise 100 times. This function takes a while to run each time, which is why I am trying to parallelize the computation or send it to background workers.

I have tried to use multiprocessing Pool, but this seems to be tied to CPU cores, not GPU.

I have attempted to solve the question here ([How to launch 100 workers in multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70626493/how-to-launch-100-workers-in-multiprocessing/70626528#70626528)), but these responses apply to CPU.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, in advance!

Comment: you'll have much better luck here if you create a minimal reproducible example of the code you've tried and how you've determined it's not parallelized how you want

Comment: I would brocast your data into an N x 100 array of noise and use numpy to vectorize the operation before getting to GPU stuff

Comment: Kernel functions running on a GPU are already running in parallel, so you cannot speed up the execution by running multiple kernels at the same time unless the kernel only use a part of the GPU which is rare, or if you have multiple GPUs (and the kernel only use one of them). Still, CUDA/OpenCL functions should be serialized anyway in most case (especially when it is done from a Python code that is likely calling many GPU runtime functions).