# Passing sympy lambda to multiprocessing.Pool.map

Tags: python, multiprocessing, sympy

I want to execute a sympy lambda function in parallel.
I don't know:

- why it works in parallel although it is a lambda function
- why it stops working when I try executing without the pool
- why it works if I uncomment the first return in `lambdify`

And apparently the markdown preprocessor needs a line of text above the code so this is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

import sympy
from sympy.abc import x

def f(m):
    return m.lambdify()(1)

class Mult():
    def lambdify(self):
        # return sympy.lambdify(x, 2*x, 'numpy')
        self._lambdify = sympy.lambdify(x, 2 * x, 'numpy')
        return self._lambdify

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as pool:
        m = Mult()
        print(pool.map(f, [m]))
        print(pool.map(f, [m]))
        print(f(m))
        print(pool.map(f, [m]))
```

It prints:

```
[2]
[2]
2
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x000000000DF0D048>: attribute lookup <lambda> on numpy failed
```

(I cut the traceback)

If I uncomment, it works normally:

```
[2]
[2]
2
[2]
```

I tested only on Windows and it works exactly the same with 'numexpr' instead of 'numpy'.

Comment: You cannot call methods on instances of _live_ objects across processes using `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` unless you go out of your way to explain the targeted subprocess how to reconstruct your _live_ object on its side. For an example, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186168/7553525).

Comment: @zwer Of course, but it does not explain the points 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object `Mult` has no fields when it is created. It can thus be pickled with the stock `pickle` library. Then, when you call `lambdify`, you add a `_lambdify` attribute to the object containing a `lambda` expression, which cannot be pickled. This causes a failure in the `map` function

This explains why before calling `lambdify` you can pickle the object and use `Pool.map` and why it fails after the call.
When you uncomment the line in `lambdify`, you do not add the attribute to the class, and the `Mult` object can still be pickled after calling `lambdify`.

Comment: It sounds like it explains everything. Do you have a reference for "you add a _lambdify attribute to the object containing a lambda expression, which cannot be pickled"?

Comment: [This reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#id2) explain why lambda expression cannot be pickled. Note that apparently, [`dill`](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill) can serialize the result from `sympy.lambdify`.

Comment: My bad, `dill` also fails to pickle `sympy` objects.

Comment: Oh excuse me, I didn't understand what you said the first time. You are totally right. The thing that changes is that I try to pickle an object that contains a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not fully explored this yet, I just want to put on record that the  same example works just fine when using loky instead of multiprocessing:

```py
from loky import get_reusable_executor

import sympy
from sympy.abc import x

def f(m):
    return m.lambdify()(1)

class Mult():
    def lambdify(self):
#        return sympy.lambdify(x, 2*x, 'numpy')
        self._lambdify = sympy.lambdify(x, 2 * x, 'numpy')
        return self._lambdify


executor = get_reusable_executor()

m = Mult()
print('pool.map(f, [m])', list(executor.map(f, [m])))
print('pool.map(f, [m])', list(executor.map(f, [m])))
print('f(m)', f(m))
print('pool.map(f, [m])', list(executor.map(f, [m])))
```

with output

```
pool.map(f, [m]) [2]
pool.map(f, [m]) [2]
f(m) 2
pool.map(f, [m]) [2]
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, loky is amazing. The interface of [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is quite useful too.